# Is a HTTP server needed for a python webapp?

Tags: python, apache, web-applications, nginx

A complete Python website can be launched by executing WSGI application(./wsgiapp.py) as there is web framework, template engine and WSGI interface which can provide HTTP service. Under such circumstances, do we still need to install an HTTP server like Apache or nginx?

If we should have an HTTP server, what is an appropriate way to use it? Should we put static resources(css, js, etc..) and template files in the www directory?

Comment: Generally speaking, you should have all static resources served by a WebServer (put them in the www directory). The Web server (like apache etc) should talk to your application server (WSGI). In other words, the application server should be reachable only via the Web Server. Frameworks like Django explicitly recommends this.

Comment: If you are using NGINX, no need to put static files in www directory.You can specify static folder in nginx configuration file for your server

Answer (score 0):

You can use [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/) or many other web framework for python.
Twisted.web for example is good for making your own web server.
You can customize it in many way. so you can import [WSGI](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.1.0/web/howto/web-in-60/wsgi.html) and run your own application on it.
You can also put static resources and template file.
In such case you don't need apache or Nginx.
As server you can also use the more lightway but not [recommended for production](https://www.mail-archive.com/web-sig@python.org/msg00954.html)(I remember there is some other mail about this, but I couldn't find :/), like [BaseHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html#module-BaseHTTPServer) or SimpleHTTPServer or CGIHTTPServer.
you can just run like this:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
```

Because you can customize as you like it didn't have to be under www directory but is anyway good practice to use such directory, like suggested by the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html).
For be FHS compliant you have to put your data for services provided by your system under /srv folder.
Divided by protocol like:
/srv/www/